# UILabel AutoResize Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning Swift, but I Have two "stupid" Problems.

the first, I'd like autosize my UILabel
The second, I have another UIlabel and I want to put name and surname in it's field

I tried with

```
@IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!

title.text = currentPerson?.name+""+currentPerson?.surname
```

But I have this error

> Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use
>   "!" or "?" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally advised to ask 1 question per post so you get clear responses & don't mix topics, but...

1. In XCode storyboard "Attributes Inspector" you can change "Autoshrink" from "Fixed Font Size" to minimum font size or scale. Also change "Lines" from default 1 to 0. You'd also need to set some AutoLayout constraints to pin the label to superview or other elements in a way that will allow it to scale. Can't say more w/o seeing storyboard.
2. By using optional chaining to set the label text you're trying to set the label's `.text` property to an optional type `String?`  instead of a `String`. Those aren't equivalent. An optional of type `String?` *might* contain a String, or it might be nil. The UILabel expects you to use a `String` instance, so it's complaining about the mismatch.

One approach is to explicitly check the optional value against `nil`:

```
if currentPerson != nil {
   title.text = "\(currentPerson.name) \(currentPerson.surname)" 
}
else {
   title.text = ""
}
```

Swift's optional binding is similar to the first option, but you create a temporary constant and can reference its properties. If `currentPerson` is not `nil`, then the `if` block executes.

```
// current convention would be to use "currentPerson" on both sides, which can be confusing. The left side is a temporary constant & the right side is the optional property you've declared somewhere above 
if let aPerson = currentPerson { 
  title.text = "\(aPerson.name) \(aPerson.surname)"   
}
else {
   title.text = ""
}
```

Alternatively, as the error message suggests, you could Force Unwrap the optional value to access the name properties:

```
title.text = currentPerson!.name + " " + currentPerson!.surname
```

This assumes that `currentPerson` is never nil. If it *is* nil, your app will crash here.

Also note you can concatenate using `+` and `" "` or with string interpolation.

Comment: Thanks for Reply, the strings are concat. About my first problem. I Modified Autoshrink with minimum font Scale, I added constraints, even Bottom constraints. My Label is under my BottomNavigationBar. Can I use Playground with my StoryBoard, or I have to Build each time?